# How to install a rpm package as static library on RHEL 6?

Tags: static-libraries, rpm

I have install libXpm-3.5.8-2.el6.x86_64 rpm package on RHEL.
I want to install libXpm-3.5.8-2.el6.x86_64 rpm package as a static library.

RHEL 6 :

```
[root@ebw-brims2-server XPM]# rpm -qa | grep Xpm
libXpm-3.5.8-2.el6.x86_64
[root@ebw-brims2-server XPM]# yumdownloader libXpm-3.5.8-2.el6.x86_64
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhui-lb
libXpm-3.5.8-2.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                    |  59 kB     00:00
[root@ebw-brims2-server XPM]# ll
total 60
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 60208 Apr 16  2014 libXpm-3.5.8-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

I want to install above rpm package libXpm-3.5.8-2.el6.x86_64.rpm as static library at /usr/local/lib.
Please suggest , how to install rpm package as static library.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how RPMs work. If the package doesn't include the static libraries (sometimes the `package-devel` RPM does), then they're not available. You'll have to build from source.

Comment: or issue a feature request to RHEL's bugzilla

Comment: I've had bugs sitting around for years; rebuilding it yourself would probably be faster. ;)

Comment: @aaron-d-marasco agree :)